# Kohana with cherokee

Tags: mod-rewrite, kohana

How to setup kohana's index.php with cherokee webserver?

Should i add a rule to redirect all to index.php?

These settings don't work

```
Rule RegExp ^.*index.php.*$
Redirect ^(.*)$ => index.php$1
```

Comment: Have you tried the process suggested in the accepted answer to [How to port Apache rewrite rules to cherokee?](http://serverfault.com/questions/118208/how-to-port-apache-rewrite-rules-to-cherokee) at ServerFault?

Comment: I tried gives me 413

Comment: it continues looping indexphp/index.php/.../index.php/actualthing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try changing

```
Redirect ^(.*)$ => index.php$1
```

to be:

```
Redirect ^(.*)$ => /index.php?$1
```

You may need to play around, the addition of `/` and `?` are intended to stop the looping. `/` alone may be sufficient.

You might find [this answer on server fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/270968/apache-mod-rewrite-not-configured-properly/272714#272714) relevant to your issue - even if cherokee and kohanna have their own syntaxes.